# GridView delete command not firing in server. Locally works

Tags: asp.net

I have this gridview, that works perfectly when running in local computer. Platform is VWD 2010 - Sql Server

```
<asp:GridView ID="Gv_Usuarios" runat="server" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
   DataKeyNames="Login,ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EnableModelValidation="True" 
   Width="619px">
   <Columns>                    
  <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
CausesValidation="False"         CommandName="Delete"  OnClientClick='if  
(!confirm("Borra?")) return false;'  Text="Delete" />

 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

   <asp:BoundField DataField="Tipo" HeaderText="Tipo" SortExpression="Tipo" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="Nombre" HeaderText="Nombre"  SortExpression="Nombre" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="Login" HeaderText="Login" ReadOnly="True" 
                                SortExpression="Login" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="Password" HeaderText="Password" 
                                SortExpression="Password" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="Vendedor" HeaderText="Vendedor" 
                                SortExpression="Vendedor" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="Sucursal" HeaderText="Sucursal" 
                               SortExpression="Sucursal" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="Almacen" HeaderText="Almacen" 
                                SortExpression="Almacen" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="Fecha" HeaderText="Fecha" SortExpression="Fecha" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
                                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
</Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Browser fire the confirmation question, but after hittting YES, nothing happens.
It works fine in my computer, nothing happens in the hosting server.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you trying to do this from a browser on the server?

Comment: why not "return confirm("Borra?");" ?

Comment: Doing it from a browser outside the server - the same program works perfectly here. One thing: the server is running the same windows 2003 server, only in a different language.

Answer (score -1):

Use `asp:Button` instead of `asp:LinkButton`